# Python encode() and decode() string methods

Tags: python

Learning Python, increasingly frustrated with it's documentation.

For the following script:

```
utf_string = "文言"

raw_bytes = b'\xe6\x96\x87\xe8\xa8\x80'

print(raw_bytes.decode())

print(utf_string.encode())

print(raw_bytes == utf_string.encode())

print(utf_string == raw_bytes.decode())
```

1) Where is the documentation for these encode() and decode() methods?

2) I've tested for the data type of the variables using print(type(utf_string)) and realise that I am working with both strings and bytes.

3) How do I approach finding out which class these methods belong to? I've tried searching Google for 'Python 3 string methods' and 'Python decode method' with no joy.

I need to know an approach so I can find out the class the method belongs to, then easily find the documentation for this. Otherwise I don't really know how to use the method.

Comment: [str.encode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=decode#str.encode) and [bytes.decode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=decode#bytes.decode)

Comment: First Google hit for "Python 3 string methods" for me was "Built-in Types — Python 3.7.2 documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html), which has sections for classes `str` (of which `encode()` is a method) and `bytes` (of which `decode()` is a method).  You could have determined these types via `print(type(raw_bytes))` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `raw_bytes` is not a string, it is of type `bytes`. That is what the `b` prefix means. `decode` is a method of `bytes` objects and the default encoding is UTF-8 but you can specify other encodings.

Your variable `utf_string` is a string. `encode` is a string method. The default encoding is UTF-8 but you can specify other encodings.

Together these two methods, as you have discovered, enable back-and-forth translation between `bytes`, which is  immutable like a string, but is a sequence of small integers, and strings, which represent Unicode codepoints. Both methods are documented at in the Python [standard library docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html).

The Python Standard Library has, in general, exemplary documentation, and that documentation should be your first port of call when you have a question like this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Documentation for both can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html). Search for 'bytes.decode' and 'str.encode'.
2. Apparent from (1).
3. You may use `help(<type>)`, e.g. `help(str)`, in python shell to see methods (and other things) available for the corresponding object type.